# Mathematica code: Derivative of Abs[x]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

**Note to closers** : This is a question about a Programming language ([**Mathematica**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/)), and not about a discipline/science (mathematics).

Why is

```
N[D[Sin[x], x] /. x -> Pi/4]
(*
Out -> 0.707107
*)
```

but

```
N[D[Abs[x], x] /. x -> Pi/4]
(*
Out -> Derivative[1][Abs][0.785398]
*)
```

?

And what is the better way to force a numerical result?

Comment: My bad, I read "mathematics". Ignore me.

Comment: @Leke Also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81152/retag-mathematica-to-wr-mathematica-or-something-similar.

Comment: @Leke Don't mind, it is a common mistake. But the meta community refused to change the tag name to something more descriptive.

Comment: yes Abs'[x] is not evaluated numerically; I've noticed that too in the past. I'd also like to know why.

Comment: @acl And that impacts on other functions like `EuclideanDistance` that use `Abs[ ]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Abs[z]` is not a [holomorphic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), so its derivative is not well defined on the complex plane (the default domain that Mathematica works with). This is in contradistinction to, e.g., `Sin[z]`, whose complex derivative (i.e., with respect to its argument) is always defined.

More simply put, `Abs[z]` depends on both `z` and `z*`, so should really be thought as a two argument function. `Sin[z]` only depends on `z`, so makes sense with a single argument.

As pointed out by [Leonid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331080/mathematica-code-derivative-of-absx/6331248#6331248), once you restrict the domain to the reals, then the derivative is well defined (except maybe at `x=0`, where they've taken the average of the left and right derivatives)

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[Abs'[x],x \[Element] Reals]
Out[1]= Sign[x]
```

As pointed out by [Szabolcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331080/mathematica-code-derivative-of-absx/6331205#6331205) (in a comment), `FunctionExpand` will simplify the numerical expressions, but "Some transformations used by FunctionExpand are only generically valid".

`ComplexExpand` also gives numeric results, but I don't trust it. It seems to take the derivative assuming the `Abs` is in the real domain, then substitutes in the numeric/complex arguments. That said, if you know that everything you're doing is in the reals, then `ComplexExpand` is your friend.

Comment: So, here is the reason. Thanks!

Comment: but then what is the reason to not evaluate Abs'[.42]?  I am not convinced that what you say justifies it (although it's true of course)

Comment: @acl: I think because `Abs'[.42] = Limit[(Abs[z+.42] - Abs[.42])/z, z->0]` and the limit is not the same in all complex directions. Consider the path `z[t_] := 1-Exp[I t]` As `t->0`, `z[t]->0` and the limit/derivative in this direction is always zero. (This is basically reiterating my answer... oh well)

Comment: Thanks. I realise that `Abs[x]` isn't analytic, since obviously the Cauchy-Riemann conditions can't be satisfied. My comment was based on believing that mma would pretend only the real line existed if one used reals as arguments in functions other than Abs, so this would be inconsistent. However I just tried `Re'[.42]` and so on and they also remain unevaluated (while I thought I remembered it being evaluated to 1), so I guess I simply remembered something else...

Answer (score 8):

I refer you to [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/c1d6708e827a7189) thread as possibly relevant - this issue has been discussed before. To summarize my answer there,   Abs is defined generally on complex numbers. Once you specify that your argument is real, it works:

```
 In[1]:= FullSimplify[Abs'[x], Assumptions -> {Element[x, Reals]}] 

 Out[1]= Sign[x]
```

Comment: @Leonid but as you point out in that thread, it does not work for specific real arguments. And for instance, Abs'[.23] does not evaluate
while IntegerPart'[.23] does. Not terribly consistent, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @belisarius Oh, I see, you were mostly asking about numerics. Sorry, I wasn't reading your question carefully enough. It is interesting that while `FunctionExpand` seems to always work, `FullSimplify` works on integers but not reals.

Comment: @acl Yes, I agree, does not look very consistent to me. I can understand that it may be desirable to not evaluate automatically on symbolic or integer arguments, but once they are real or `N` is applied, it should have given a numeric answer.

Comment: @Leonid your last comment is a much better formulation of my question!

Comment: @Leonid: Even with specific real values, the derivative is not well defined. The value only defines the point at which you examine the derivative, not the direction. `FunctionExpand` seems to be making an (almost reasonable) assumption about the domain.

Comment: @Simon This crossed my mind. You are saying that all functions are considered as functions of complex variable, and even if the value happens to be real, we don't know how the limit is taken for the derivative - or on the real line, whether we ask about left and right derivative. Makes sense, but then I'd prefer a more sophisticated functionality allowing me to specify the limiting procedure or at least (possibly optionally) issuing a warning on numerical arguments.

Comment: @Leonid: I assume that is what's happening, since nearly everywhere else, Mma assumes complex variables. And I agree that maybe a more sophisticated functionality or ability to change the default domain would be nice, but then would that be traded off against power/speed/consistency?

Comment: @Simon I think it can be made reasonably fast and yet powerful and consistent (just my impression). I am also sure that WRI is aware of this issue and some work in this direction may possibly be underway.

Comment: @Leonid This is helpful. But I was wondering, if the arguement is complex. In my case I have `Abs'[a + i b]`, form. Does this still work? Instead of `FullSimplify`, `Simplify` doesn't seem to work :(. Bcuz `FullSimply` takes lot of time for big expressions.

Comment: @L.K. You would have to indicate the direction along which you are taking the derivative in this case, since `Abs` is not an analytic function of a variable, in the complex plane. I did a few simple experiments, which indicate that the method from the answer does not work in this case, though. You may also look at `ComplexExpand`, which can be useful in such cases. But in general it looks like one has to do considerably more work to simplify for cases like you mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `FunctionExpand` to force getting a number as a result even when you are using exact quantities:

```
Abs'[Pi/4] // FunctionExpand
Abs'[-1] // FunctionExpand
```

I do not know the reason for the following though:

```
In:= Abs'[0] // FunctionExpand
Out= 0
```

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. Do you know why this is necessary? I mean ... why Mma does not evaluate this as usual?

Comment: +1, had no idea about FunctionExpand! Curious why IntegerPart'[x] evaluates for numerical x but Abs'[x] does not though.

Comment: The last bit is probably due to convention (strictly the value is undefined because the derivative does not exist).

Comment: @Szabolcs Why do you think that anything is wrong with the second answer? This is consistent with the definition of `Sign[x]`, as long as we agree that `Abs'[x] == Sign[x]` for real `x`.

Comment: @Leonid, the reason is what @rubenvb said.  It's not mathematically precise.  And *maybe* this is the reason why it's not evaluated automatically, @belisarius.  Under "Possible issues" the doc page says: "Some transformations used by FunctionExpand are only generically valid."  Leonid is right that the "imprecise" result appears because `Abs'[x]` is expanded to `Sign[x]`: `FunctionExpand[Abs'[x], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: @Leonid, ah, sorry, I just saw your answer!